# Unexpected error occurred: Micronaut Data method is missing compilation time query information

Tags: maven, kotlin, micronaut-data

I'm facing this problem with micronaut. I followed the documentation, but it might be something missing because every time I try to access a repository it comes out this erro:

> [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] ERROR i.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - Unexpected error occurred: Micronaut Data method is missing compilation time query information. Ensure that the Micronaut Data annotation processors are declared in your build and try again with a clean re-build.

Anyone can help?

here is my pom :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>victorinno.com.github</groupId>
    <artifactId>pet_shop_kotlin_lab</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <jdk.version>11</jdk.version>
        <release.version>11</release.version>
        <micronaut.version>2.1.2</micronaut.version>
        <exec.mainClass>victorinno.com.github.ApplicationKt</exec.mainClass>
        <micronaut.jaxrs.version>1.0.2</micronaut.jaxrs.version>
        <micronaut.data.version>2.1.0</micronaut.data.version>
        <kotlinVersion>1.4.10</kotlinVersion>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter.bintray.com</id>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
                <artifactId>testcontainers-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.14.3</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-inject</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-http-server-netty</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-http-client</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlinVersion}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlinVersion}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-kotlin-runtime</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-runtime</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-jdbc-hikari</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-data-hibernate-jpa</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-kotlin-extension-functions</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-jaxrs-server</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-test-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.micronaut.build</groupId>
                <artifactId>micronaut-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <version>${kotlinVersion}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmTarget>${jdk.version}</jvmTarget>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>jpa</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                    <pluginOptions>
                        <option>jpa:annotation=io.micronaut.aop.Around</option>
                    </pluginOptions>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>kapt</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>kapt</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                            <annotationProcessorPaths>
                                <annotationProcessorPath>
                                    <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>micronaut-inject-java</artifactId>
                                    <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                                </annotationProcessorPath>
                                <annotationProcessorPath>
                                    <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
                                    <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                                </annotationProcessorPath>
                                <annotationProcessorPath>
                                    <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>micronaut-data-processor</artifactId>
                                    <version>${micronaut.data.version}</version>
                                </annotationProcessorPath>
                                <annotationProcessorPath>
                                    <groupId>io.micronaut.jaxrs</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>micronaut-jaxrs-processor</artifactId>
                                    <version>${micronaut.jaxrs.version}</version>
                                </annotationProcessorPath>
                            </annotationProcessorPaths>
                            <annotationProcessorArgs>
                                <annotationProcessorArg>micronaut.processing.group=victorinno.com.github
                                </annotationProcessorArg>
                                <annotationProcessorArg>micronaut.processing.module=pet_shop_kotlin_lab
                                </annotationProcessorArg>
                            </annotationProcessorArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-kapt</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-kapt</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                            <annotationProcessorPaths>
                                <annotationProcessorPath>
                                    <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>micronaut-inject-java</artifactId>
                                    <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                                </annotationProcessorPath>
                                <annotationProcessorPath>
                                    <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
                                    <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                                </annotationProcessorPath>
                                <annotationProcessorPath>
                                    <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>micronaut-data-processor</artifactId>
                                    <version>${micronaut.data.version}</version>
                                </annotationProcessorPath>
                                <annotationProcessorPath>
                                    <groupId>io.micronaut.jaxrs</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>micronaut-jaxrs-processor</artifactId>
                                    <version>${micronaut.jaxrs.version}</version>
                                </annotationProcessorPath>
                            </annotationProcessorPaths>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</sourceDir>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/kapt/test</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlinVersion}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4.10</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <proc>none</proc>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-compile</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-testCompile</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>java-compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>java-test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

and the repository

```
package victorinno.com.github.repository

import io.micronaut.data.annotation.Repository
import io.micronaut.data.repository.CrudRepository
import victorinno.com.github.data.Tag

@Repository
interface TagRepository : CrudRepository<Tag, Long>
```

The mapped entity

```
package victorinno.com.github.data


import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue
import javax.persistence.GenerationType
import javax.persistence.Id

@Entity
data class Tag(
        @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) var id: Long,
        var name: String)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem,
[image]

---

You need to add a path of the annotation processor JAR manually.

```
 <annotationProcessorPaths                       
                  combine.children="append">
         <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-data-processor</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
         </path>
  </annotationProcessorPaths>
```

The processor is separated from the actual project dependencies. This option is also picked up by the Eclipse M2E plug-in if annotation processing is enabled for the project.

**Complete Pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.knf.dev.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>micronaut-data-jpa-crud</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>${packaging}</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <jdk.version>11</jdk.version>
        <release.version>11</release.version>
        <micronaut.version>3.1.1</micronaut.version>
        <exec.mainClass>org.knf.dev.demo.Application</exec.mainClass>
        <micronaut.runtime>netty</micronaut.runtime>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-inject</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-test-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-http-client</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-http-server-netty</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-runtime</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-data-hibernate-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-jdbc-hikari</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.micronaut.build</groupId>
                <artifactId>micronaut-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Uncomment to enable incremental compilation -->
                    <!-- <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation> -->

                    <annotationProcessorPaths
                        combine.children="append">
                        <path>
                            <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
                            <artifactId>micronaut-data-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.group=org.knf.dev.demo</arg>
                        <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.module=micronaut-data-jpa-crud</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly add the configuration and executions annotation in your pom.xml

```
    <configuration>
                <!-- Uncomment to enable incremental compilation -->
                <!-- <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation> -->
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                        <artifactId>micronaut-inject-java</artifactId>
                        <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                        <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
                        <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
                        <artifactId>micronaut-data-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.1</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.group=com.hkg.micronaut.airport</arg>
                    <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.module=airport-service</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <annotationProcessorPaths>
                            <path>
                                <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                                <artifactId>micronaut-inject-java</artifactId>
                                <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                            </path>
                            <path>
                                <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                                <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
                                <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                            </path>

                            <path>
                                <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
                                <artifactId>micronaut-data-processor</artifactId>
                                <version>2.0.1</version>
                            </path>
                        </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
```